# How to preserve order of attributes when am modifying value in xml configuration file?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

When modifying attribute of xml configuration file the order of attributes are changing.

```
Before modifying xml: <connection user="testing" intervalInSeconds="50" versionUpdates="10" />

After modifying xml: <connection intervalInSeconds="50" user="testing" versionUpdates="10" />
```

How to preserve order of attributes in python 3?

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file path')
root = tree.getroot()

# modifying an attribute
for elem in root.iter('connection'):

    elem.set('versionUpdates', '10')

tree.write('file path', encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the following way, maintains the order  - not sure why doing it your way doesn't:

```
mystr = """
<connection user="testing" intervalInSeconds="50" versionUpdates="10" />
"""

from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(mystr)
for elem in root.iter('connection'):
    elem.set('versionUpdates', '20') #note: I changed it to '20', just to check
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

Output:

```
b'<connection user="testing" intervalInSeconds="50" versionUpdates="20"/>\n'
```

So modification is implemented, but order is maintained. Not sure if it helps your specific situation, but it may be an option.

Comment: You're using lxml. He's using standard ElementTree. ElementTree doesn't preserve the order of attributes. lxml does.

Comment: @George - Since I don't use ElementTree much (if at all), I didn't realize ElementTree doesn't preserve the order of attributes! Learn something new every day...Thanks.

Comment: Update: This is supposedly no longer true as of Python 3.8.0: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/63673916464bace8e2147357395fdf3497967ecb